# How to efficiently use items in a game I'm playing.

Tags: percentages

Ok so this has been bugging me for some time now and my brain is just to small so I'm hoping some of you here can help me with this problem.

The goal is to get as much points as possible over time with three different items. 
These items are used six at a time. They give a set amount of points and also come with a percentage chance to double said amount of points.

First item gives 800 points with a 5% chance of a bonus

Second item gives 400 points with a 20% chance of a bonus

Third item gives 100 points with a 10% chance of a bonus

You can mix any of these items but the maximum amount of items used is six. 
The points add up and the bonus chance also adds up.

For example you can use three of the first item and three of the third item and you would get 2700 points with a 45% chance of the points being doubled.

Which is the most efficient composition of items to get most points over time?

Comment: What happens if you pick six of the second item? What does 120% chance represent?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the percentage chance is capped at 100%

Comment: compound or simple interest ?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you should not use any of item $3$ as item $2$ is strictly better.  I just made a spreadsheet assuming the chance of a bonus is capped at $100\%$
[image]
The expected score is best with $4$ of item $1$ and $2$ of item $2$, but $5/1$ is very close.

Comment: Thank you Ross!
How do you calculate the expected score if you don't mind me asking? What is the formula?

Comment: The expected score is points * (1 + bonus / 100).

Comment: It is just the average of the total points weighted by the probability to get them.  Here it is base points times (1+bonus/100)  It is the average number of points you will get per try over the long term

Comment: Thanks again! Have a good day